# Attribute with multiple values in rails: booleans, string and serialize or hbtm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, checkbox, boolean, serialization

Say you have a Book model that can belong to multiple categories. Categories are predefined, but we might let the user add his own even though most of the time default ones are enough.

What is the best way to deal with that according to you ?

a) a many to many relationship to a Category model ? But isn't that overkill given the fact default categories are enough most of the time ?
b) booleans for each default category and an extra string for user entered categories
C) just a string and the use of serialize ? But then it might be a bit more tricky to use checkbox inputs for the default choices
d) any other suggestion of yours...

Thanks for your time!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `HABTM`. It's not overkill if you're ever going to want to collect any sort of information about the various categories; date created, for example. You'll also gain the ability to easily fetch all books for a given category without having to worry about scopes inside the book model.

Also, down the road you might want to be able to add other objects to categories. There's not much overhead, and it's quite simple to set up, so worth going for, IMHO.

For help on implementing `HABTM` with checkboxes, check out the [HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) railscast. For a discussion of the differences between `HABTM` and `has_many :through`, I really recommend the [Two Many-to-Many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) railscasts.

Comment: If you want to collect info on the categories, then you'll need to set it up as a :has_many :through => relationship. HABTM is kinda falling out of favor for this reason.

Comment: I meant on each category object itself -- that's certainly true for tracking any information on the join between a category and a book. It seems like those railscasts show the only valid use of HABTM... some category implementations.

Comment: What about performances in that case? It seems to me that using hbtm will require the implementation of some eager loading or caching later on, but perhaps earlier than with the other solutions. Especially if there a couple other attributes like Category. Am I wrong to believe that?

Comment: Not sure about the perfomance aspect -- if you ever want to expand the list, the only other reasonable option is has_many :through, and that's certainly slower (though it does let you track attributes of the join).